# Regex, avoid matching consecutive characters

Tags: regex

I m trying to improve my regex skills.
I can't manage this exercise.

https://alf.nu/RegexGolf

You have to match words without consecutive identical characters.
To make it clear, we should avoid patterns like abba, or baab, czzc.

The only way I see is to use capture groups:

```
([a-z])([a-z])\2\1
```

Then have a negative lookahead:

```
(?!([a-z])([a-z])\2\1)
```

But on the site it doesn't work since it doesn't match anything.

Any advice?
Thank you

Comment: I think that would be `[a-z]*foo[a-z]*` The matches all have foo between optional char a-z on the left and the right. With a capturing group it could be `^[a-z]*f(.)\1[a-z]*$`

Comment: That's the answer of the first exercice, I m on the 6th one "abba"
The words to avoid are:
abba 
anallagmatic
bassarisk
chorioallantois
coccomyces
commotive
engrammatic
glossoscopia
hexacoralla
hippogriffin
inflammableness
otto
overattached
saffarid
sarraceniaceae
scillipicrin
tlapallan
trillion
unclassably
nfitting
unsmelled
warrandice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to Tim Biegeleisen, here is the answer.
`^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1).*$`

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$
```

Explanation:

```
^               from the start of the input
    (?:
        (.)     match AND capture a single character
        (?!\1)  then assert that what follows is a different character (not the same)
    )*          match zero or more such matching characters
$               end of the input
```

### Demo

Another, possibly cleaner, way to do this would be to just have a global negative lookahead at the very start of the pattern:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1).*$
```

This would assert at the very beginning that no character is duplicated, anywhere in the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
You helped a lot. I wanted to reject patterns like abba caac but accept abbc caab so I tweeked a bit your answer.

````^(?!.*(.)(.)\2\1).*$````

Answer (score 0):

^(?!cr|pal|tar)[a-z]{1,4}([a-z])\1[a-z]{0,5}$
This worked for me in the link you gave. I guess we had to match patterns with consecutive letters. But there were some exceptions for which I had to use negative look ahead at the beginning. I have used ([a-z])\1 to match consecutive characters surrounded by possible characters of possible limit. Hope this helps!
Attached the screenshot for reference.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/va1Uq.png